# Array radio button on dynamic added row

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have a form that allowed user add row dynamically. Inside the form have array radio button.

**Question:**

1. When I try click on second row's radio button or other raw, the radio button value will show in first column only and other have an offset error.

   At the beginning, in my concept is the value will stored according to array column turned out is not.
2. So, I try using JavaScript to set each raw radio button's value but it show this error:

   > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var radioB = document.getElementById(BX_related);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
       // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
   
   var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
   newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML; //row[which table u need to duplicate]
   table.rows[rowCount].cells[0].innerHTML = rowCount;
   }
   radioB[rowCount].value = rowCount;

}
```

```html
<table id="dataTable" class="form" border="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr><th>Bil.</th><th>Nama</th><th>Umur</th><th>Dij./Ting.</th><th>Pekerjaan</th><th>Catatan</th><th>Berkenaan</th></tr>
  <tr ><td>1</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="BX_name[]" size="30"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="BX_age[]"size="2" ></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="BX_study[]"size="8"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="BX_work[]" size="10"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="BX_note[]"size="15"></td>
  <td> <input type="radio" name="BX_related[]" id="BX_related" value="" required></td></tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

**The PHP part:**

```
<?php 
            $i =0;
            if(isset($_POST)=='submit'){

                $BX_name=$_POST['BX_name'];
                $BX_age=$_POST['BX_age'];
                $BX_related = $_POST['BX_related'];         
                echo $BX_related;
                foreach($BX_name as $a => $b)
                    {   
                        $i ++;                              
                    echo "<br> $i";
                        echo "name: ";
                        echo $BX_name[$a];
                    }

}
            ?>
```

Anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Dynamically added rows will have the same id. Hence the error. just remove the id and add a class to get the row and insert.

Comment: Hi Amit, I don't understand. Have any example on this issue? Thanks

Comment: while inserting rows dynamically you need to change the id of BX_related to some random id everytime. thats what i mean. hope u got the catch !!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="radio" name="BX_related[]" id="BX_related" value="" required>
```

to

```
<input type="radio" name="BX_related[]" class="BX_related" value="" required></td>
```

Also in addRow function , instead of

```
  var radioB = document.getElementById(BX_related);
```

use

```
  var radioB = document.getElementsByClassName('BX_related);
```

Thats it!!